# Checking if a function is a solution to a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is [image]a solution to the differential equation [image]?

I know that [image] is the same thing as the differential equation but I am not sure as to how I should continue

Comment: Can you differentiate $A(t)$?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Is that a $.25t$ there? If so then it is clearly not a solution.

Comment: Yes, it's a $.25t$ which is why I was confused myself.

Comment: You can solve the equation but you can’t differentiate the supposed solution to check it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's separate and integrate:

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 25(A-40)$$
$$\frac{dA}{(A-40)} = 25 dt$$
$$\int \frac{dA}{(A-40)} = \int 25 dt$$
$$\ln\left|A-40\right| = 25t+C_0 $$
$$A = 40 + e^{25t+C_0}$$
$$A = 40 + C_1 e^{25t}$$

In order for $40 + 50e^{.25t}$ to be a solution, we need to be able to rewrite it into the form $40 + C_1 e^{25t}$ so that it is true for all $t$.

$$40 + 50e^{.25t}$$
$$40 + 50e^{25t-24.75t}$$
$$40 + (50e^{-24.75t}) e^{25t} $$
But we see that $50e^{-24.75t}$ is not a constant, as it contains a $t$. Therefore it couldn't possibly be a solution.

---

If by some chance the $.25$ should have been a $25$, then it should be straightforward to see what the answer would be.